# Command line installing PJSIP

Tags: ios, command-line, pjsip

I am following this to set up pjsip for iPhone.

http://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/iPhone

I follow up to where I run ./configure-iphone and everything is good, these run fine, I can get into the directory and run these.

$ cd /path/to/your/pjsip/dir
$ ARCH='-arch armv7s' ./configure-iphone

but then I need to run "make dep && make clean && make" and I get this:

make: *** /Users/Me: Is a directory.  Stop.

I have Xcode command line tools installed, what is my problem here?

Comment: Does your username have spaces in it? Or is it literally "Me"? Spaces could cause problems with some scripts.

Comment: Ah yes, it does. Do you know how I could solve this? Without changing my username?

Comment: Usually, in build scripts that have problems with spaces, you solve it by putting quotes around variables, like `"$this"`. Not sure if it will work here, though. First, try making a test user with no spaces to see if it really is the problem.